# How to add cookie hash as key for TYPO3-Caching

Tags: caching, cookies, typo3

I want a TYPO3 CMS 9.x to cache different page variants, depending on a cookie hash.

- page without cookie: default variant
- page with hash in cookie: hash variant
- page with other hash in cookie: other hash variant

How and where can I affect the caching for this?